# unresolved compilation using hbase in java

Tags: java, hbase, hadoop2

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;                        
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;                          
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;                           
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;        
Import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;                           

public class HBaseConnection                            
{                           
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException                       
    {                           
        HBaseConfiguration hc = new HBaseConfiguration(new Configuration());                                        
        HTableDescriptor ht = new HTableDescriptor("guru99");                                       

        ht.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("education"));                  
        ht.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("projects"));                                       
        System.out.println( "connecting" );                                     
        HBaseAdmin hba = new HBaseAdmin( hc );                              

        System.out.println( "Creating Table" );                             
        hba.createTable( ht );                          
        System.out.println("Done......");                                       

    }                       
}
```

The above is my java code that I'm using to connect my hbase with my java api, but I get an error as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   error

I cleaned the project and tried running it again, I have added all the external jar files that HBase has, by the im using HBase in a pseudo distribution mode with hadoop, and at the top of my eclipse I also get an error as

> The type com.google.com.protobuf.GeneratedMessage$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: Sounds like you're missing the protobuf jar file from the classpath. As an aside, always check for compilation errors *before* trying to run the code - it's very rarely worth running code when you've still got a compilation error.

Comment: should i create a new file then?

Comment: No, you should add the protobuf dependency to the classpath.

Comment: thank you! i did so